# uint8_t array with dynamic variable

Tags: objective-c, c, uint8t

I have an uint8_t array:

```
uint8_t theArray[12] = { 0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0xFE,0x03,0x01,0xC1,0x00,0x01 };
```

And I need the array that has 5 of those theArrays, but first value must change by one. 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 and so on. How can I build that array without rewriting theArray multiple times?

Comment: This is C, not Objective-C and nothing to do with iOS.

Comment: Sorry, I am using it for my iOS app and writing it alongside Objective-C.

Comment: @Droppy everything which is valid C is also valid Objective-C, although this certainly isn't iOS-specific.

Comment: @Droppy Deciding every time, whether something only contains plain C is more complicated than tagging the PL, one uses. Beside this it sometimes hides the possibility to show a Objective-C solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply copy an array and change the first value.

```
uint8_t array[5][12] = {
                         { 0x00, 0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0xFE,0x03,0x01,0xC1,0x00,0x01 }
                       } ;

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++ )
{
  array[i][0] = i;
  for (int j = 1; j < 12; j++ )
  {
    array[i][j] = array[0][j];
  }
}
```

Typed in Safari.

Comment: Thank you! One more question, how should my array look if I have the array with 5 different uint8_t [12] arrays? And is it possible to have array with uint8_t [12] and uint8_t[16] arrays inside?

Comment: 1. I do not understand the Q. 2. It is not possible for stack arrays. The type of the outer array is constant for all members of the array (homogene array).  `uint8_t[12]` and `uint8_t[16]` are considered being different types. There are two solutions for heterogene arrays: Having an outer array of type `int *` and allocating the members manually using `malloc()` or having inner arrays of the largest size and simply do not use the last member of smaller arrays. Maybe Cocoa arrays (`NSMutableArray`) fulfill your requirements better.